# İs that possible to a function return String OR Int depends on address

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, string, functions

Well, I'm trying to use a HMI display and this HMI storing datas in separeta addreses. Such as integers addr. is between 0x80000 to 0x9ffff and also for string's addr is between 0 to 0x1ffff.

**At this point I want to make function which is return integer if addr is a integer addr OR it will return string if addr is String addr. is that possible to make two kind of return type for a method.**

I will detect integer or string from addr value like this:

```
????    HMT_SendCMD_ReadVPN16(INT32U Addr)  

if((Addr > 0x00080000) || (Addr < 0x0009FFFF))
    {
        return int (); // at here it call a fonction and it will return integer
    }

else if(Addr < 0x0001FFFF)
    {
         return String (); // at here it call a fonction and it will return String
    }
```

Comment: There are ways of doing it using objects, but it's really messy and convoluted and really not worth the effort. Simpler to just have two functions, one for each type.

Comment: Move your logic to a new function that works with either. Then define 2 different functions with the same name and different arguments as needed. they can be auto-magically called and C++ will detect which one you need. You then call your logic from inside each of the wrappers, so that you don't have to code the full logic twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that possible to make two kind of return type for a method

No. Functions are *declared* with a single return type. What is the point anyway of returning a blank string?

You need to redesign.

Comment: What is the point anyway of returning a blank string? - well there would be normal fuction like String abc();  I have add symbolic . anyway, if god of arduino, says no, it's over. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If the task were to store something different at the given address,

or if you would want to return a String representation of the integer,

you might be able to do so, but Majenko's comment and Nick's response, suggesting a different approach, are better.